# How to load all compiled class from a folder?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a folder operators  .In this folder I have compiled file(one interface operator AND 4 class that implement operator)  .The purpose is load all the .class file from this folder and use in the main program  . I use this statments  :

```
    File operatorFile = new File("D:\\operators");
    URL operatorFilePath = operatorFile.toURL();          
    URL[] operatorFilePaths = new URL[]{operatorFilePath};
    ClassLoader operatorsLoader = new URLClassLoader(operatorFilePaths);

 //Plus,Minus,Multiply,Divide are classes that implement operator interface
   Class[] operatorClass = new Class[]{ operatorsLoader.loadClass("Plus"), operatorsLoader.loadClass("Minus"),operatorsLoader.loadClass("Multiply") , operatorsLoader.loadClass("Divide") };
```

Then I use this statment to call .class file methods  :

```
Method methodsInOperator;
Object instance;
String operatorSign;

for(Class operatorCls : operatorClass)
{
   instance = operatorCls.newInstance();
    methodsInOperator = operatorCls.getMethod("getSign", null); 
    operatorSign = (String)methodsInOperator.invoke(instance, null);
                    if(operatorSign.equals(elementInExpression[2]))
                    {
    methodsInOperator = operatorCls.getMethod("calculate", new Class[] { double.class, double.class } ); 
                        output =(double)methodsInOperator.invoke(instance, firstNumber, secondNumber);  
                    }
                }
```

But below statment dose not work dynamically and if we put another .class file to operators folder program stop working  .

```
Class[] operatorClass = new Class[]{ operatorsLoader.loadClass("Plus"), operatorsLoader.loadClass("Minus"),operatorsLoader.loadClass("Multiply") , operatorsLoader.loadClass("Divide") };
```

My purpose is to load all classes dynamically and check if they implement operator and according to getSing() method choose the best class  .Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "program stop working". The new class doesn't come into the `opeartorClass` array?

Comment: for example i write % class and add .class into folder my program should still work

Comment: To clarify again, the new Percentage should appear in your `operatorClass` array?

Comment: yes i should load class dynamically every .class file added to the folder should aslo load

Comment: You almost certainly don't need to laod all the classes. Just the one that you use directly. The others it depends on will be loaded automatically.

Comment: Do you need all these classes to not be in your classpath? Why are you loading them manually, instead of letting the jvm do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this:

1. First list the files in the given folder.
2. Then load the class if it is of given interface/type.

I wrote a small method that does it - you can base your logic on that.

```
public Class[] getOperators(File operatorFile) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ClassLoader operatorsLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { operatorFile.toURI().toURL() });

    File[] files = operatorFile.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".class");
        }
    });
    ArrayList<Class> operators = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File file : files) {
        String className = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().length() - 6);
        Class<?> clazz = operatorsLoader.loadClass(className);
        if(OperatorInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            operators.add(clazz);
        }
    }
    return operators.toArray(new Class[operators.size()]);
}
```

If everything goes fine, calling this method with the folder should return all the classes in that folder that implement OpeartorInterface. I did not execute it - so you may have to fix some issues with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the SPI-mechanism for your problem:

1. add the directory where you have the operations classes stored to the classpath

java -cp "main.jar;operations" my.package.MainClass

2. do add an directory called "META-INF/services" in the operations directory
3. create an file which has the full qualified name of the Interface you use. For example if you interface's name is Operation and in package com.calc name the file "com.calc.Operation"
4. edit this file with the text editor of your choice. Add every implementation of your Interface by there full qualified name. Each class in a new line. Your first line would be "com.calc.Addition" the  4th line could be "com.calc.Devision" etc.
5. in you main class just use you the ServiceLocator-Class to iterate thru your implementations:

   ```
   ServiceLoader<Operation> operations = ServiceLoader.load(Operation.class);
   Iterator<Operation> ite = operations.iterator();
   while (ite.hasNext()) {
       Operation op = ite.next();
       System.out.println("operation implementation is: " + op.getClass());
       Number result = op.calc(3,4);
       System.out.println("Result of 3 and 4 is " + result);
   }
   ```

This SPI mechanism is described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html
It's an very old feature but becomes handy since the Introduction of the ServiceLocator with Java 6. Using the SPI you don't need to care for reflection or class loading

If you want to add more operations, add the class files and add a new line with the full qualified name to the file under operations/META-INF/services

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd give the [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) a chance. It's a very nice piece of software that lets you do exactly what you want:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("my.project.prefix"))
    .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner()),
    .filterInputsBy(
        new FilterBuilder().includePackage("my.project.prefix")));
```

where `my.project.prefix` points to your folder.

Then, you could simply use the `reflections` instance to get your classes:

```
Set<Class<? extends Operator>> operators = 
    reflections.getSubTypesOf(Operator.class);
```

Here, `Operator` would be your base class or interface.